# how to put a widget above a modal barrier in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a design which contains multiple columns with multiple widgets inside.

When the user clicks inside one column the rest of the screen should grey out - except the widget inside the column which is active.

For this "grey out" effect I use modal [ModalBarrier class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalBarrier-class.html).

**How can I tell a widget to appear ABOVE the modal barrier?**
(my problem is, that everything appers behind the modal barrier...)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using ``Stack`` ?

Comment: Did you found a way to accomplish this? if so, could you paste a code snippet?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
Stack(
    children: [
      new Opacity(
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: const ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Container(
          Text('Hello'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: In ModalBarrier, color can have opacity as Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3), thus avoiding the parent Opacity widget.